# Proving that for any point on an intersection of two surfaces, their respective tangent planes at the point are orthogonal.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, partial-derivative

Consider the surfaces $$x^2+y^2-2z^2=2$$ and $$(x^2+y^2)z=4$$

Prove that, for any point $p_0$, on the intersection of these two surfaces, the two tangent planes at $p_0$ are orthogonal.

Would it be satisfactory to find where the surfaces intersect and then find their respective gradient vectors? I know the tangent planes will be orthogonal if the normal line from one plane is on the tangent plane of the other which occurs if: $$\nabla f(x,y,1)\cdot \nabla g(x,y,1)=0.$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that'll be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first the intersection points are:
$$r^{2}=2+2z^{2}$$
$$r^{2}=4/z$$
$$2+2z^{2}=4/z$$
$$z=1$$
for $z=1$ we have:
$$ r=2$$
so the intersection point is:
$$x=2cos\theta ,y=2sin\theta, z=1$$

The normal of the tangent plane of the first surface:
$$ n=(2x,2y,-4z)$$

the normal of the tangent plane of the second one is:

$$n=(2xz,2yz,x^{2}+y^{2})$$

the inner product of these normal vectors are:
$$<n_{1}.n_{2}>=(4x^{2}z+4y^{2}z-4z(x^{2}+y^{2})$$

so in z=1 we have:$$ <n_{1}.n_{2}>=0$$
Notice that the inner product is always zero. I just wanted to show that these surfaces have intersection.

Comment: You get zero **everywhere**, not only at $\;z=1\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio it was more exact to write about intersection point

Comment: Perhaps, yet getting that the inner product is **always** zero makes things way easier, as we don't need to worry about any intersection point...

Comment: @DonAntonio yes but I liked to write intersection points. it shows that they have intersection. but you are right too.  I will edit my post

Comment: Good point indeed: to show there's at least one intersection point. +1

Answer (score 1):

The gradients to the surfaces are

$$\begin{align*}&\nabla_1=\left(\,2x,\,2y,\,-4z\,\right)\\{}\\
&\nabla_2=\left(\,2xz,\,2yz,\,x^2+y^2\,\right)\end{align*}$$

It is trivial now to check $\;\nabla_1\cdot\nabla_2=0\;$ **everywhere**, and thus also in any common point to the surfaces